# What is the meaning of "you look take care of her"?

Tags: meaning

I can't understand the following snippet of conversation:

> Yes. You look take care of her. She can’t handle alcohol.

What is the meaning of "you look take care of her"? That seems very odd.

Comment: No, it makes no sense. Please provide the context where this phrase occurs; it may be possible to work out what the writer intended.

Comment: "Yes. You look take care of her. She can’t handle alcohol."

Comment: @Sunny Whoever wrote that was initially thinking of saying "You *look after* her!", but later changed their mind and phrased it "You *take care* of her!", but left the original *look* in by mistake. It's an editing artifact. An oversight. A mistake. Forget about it.

Comment: I'm guessing this could be _look_ in the sense of an injunction to understand or take heed. "You... look, take care of her."

Comment: Where did you see this phrase? Have you copied it out exactly? It could be that it was written as *"You look after / take care of her. She can't handle alcohol"*. Otherwise Neil and Dan Brown have both given very good interpretations.

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Bron*, no `w` (I wouldn't mind except the guy who spells his name with a `w` .... doesn't enjoy the most sterling reputation on the internet. Also he writes drivel.)

Comment: @DanBron I'm sorry,  autopilot must have taken over. Please, forgive me!

Comment: @Mari-LouA *sit venia verbo* (sorry, I don't know how to conjugate that properly in Latin!).

Comment: Words are inverted.  Read it as "Look, you take care of her."  (The original statement likely had inflection that went "You, look, take care of her," which would make this clearer.)

Comment: This is not correct modern English.

Comment: @superluminary - Normal speech is very often "not correct" in the most literal sense.  This doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks - It may not be wrong as part of a dialect, English is a language in flux, but it's not grammatically correct standard modern English. I just wanted to point that out in case the OP hadn't realised.

Comment: @superluminary -- It's perfectly correct in dialog, where the person starts and stops and starts again,  It's even correct when written, if commas are correctly placed to indicate that "look" is essentially parenthetical.

Comment: True, but there are no commas here. It could be rewritten "Yes, you. look, take care of her. She can’t handle alcohol."

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the conversation had a pause which you have not included, and went something like "Yes. You...look, take care of her. She can't handle alcohol."

If so, the speaker was about to say something else, such as "You ought to know that she can't handle booze", but changed his mind after the first word, paused, then rephrased his request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be covered by sense 5 of the verb *look* in the OED.

> 5. trans. With clause (esp. that-clause, or clause introduced by how) as object: to take care, make sure, be mindful. Chiefly in imper. Now
>      arch. or regional.
>
> eOE   King Ælfred tr. Gregory Pastoral Care (Hatton) (1871) lix. 451
>   Lociað nu [L. videte] ðæt ðios eowru leaf ne weorðe oðrum monnum to
>   biswice.
>
> eOE   Laws of Ælfred (Corpus Cambr. 173) Introd. xii. 30   Locige þæt
>   hio hæbbe hrægl.
>
> c1150  (▸OE)    tr. Medicina de Quadrupedibus (Harl. 6258B) (1984) 239
>   Loca [OE Vitell. beheald; L. observabis] þæt þes laecedon ne hrine
>   wæteres ne eorþan.
>
> c1275  (▸?a1200)    Laȝamon Brut (Calig.) (1978) l. 8549   Loke þat þu
>   na mare swulc þing ne iscire.
>
> a1400  (▸a1325)    Cursor Mundi (Vesp.) 1966 (MED),   Fixs and flesse,
>   o bath i sai, Lok ai þe blod ȝee cast a wai.
>
> a1400  (▸a1325)    Cursor Mundi (Vesp.) l. 16814 + 15   Pilat..bad þat
>   þai suld loke þat he wore ded for-thy.
>
> ?c1425   Recipe in Coll. Ordinances Royal Househ. (1790) 434   Loke
>   hit be stondynge.
>
> ?c1430  (▸c1400)    Wyclif Eng. Wks. (1880) 38   Seynt petyr comaundiþ
>   ȝif ony speke, loke he speke as goddis wordis.
>
> ▸a1470   Malory Morte Darthur (Winch. Coll. 13) (1990) I. 35   Looke
>   every of you kyngis lat make such ordinaunce.
>
> 1561   T. Hoby tr. B. Castiglione Courtyer iii. sig. Ee.iv,   And you
>   (my L. Margaret) looke ye beare it well awaye.
>
> a1616   Shakespeare Othello (1622) iv. iii. 8   Dispatch your
>   Attendant there,—looke it be done.
>
> 1621–31   W. Laud Serm. (1847) 133   The State must look their
>   proceedings be just, and the Church must look their devotions and
>   actions be pious.
>
> 1646   J. Hall Horæ Vacivæ 22   We ought to looke how wee spend our
>   houres here.
>
> 1690   E. Gee Jesuit's Mem. 89   Censor to look that no man lived
>   idly.
>
> 1742   G. Turnbull Observ. Liberal Educ. ii. 223   Those..that intend
>   ever to govern their children should..look that they perfectly comply
>   with the will of their parents.
>
> a1822   Shelley Cyclops in Posthumous Poems (1824) 349   When I call,
>   Look ye obey the masters of the craft.
>
> 1865   Jrnl. Royal Agric. Soc. 2nd Ser. 1 ii. 242   We must look,
>   therefore, that we have the..wide chest, straight back, &c.
>
> 1926   F. M. Ford Man could stand Up i. ii. 38   Look how you let in
>   your nearest and dearest—those who have to sympathise with you.
>
> 2004   M. Walton-Roberts in P. Jackson et al. Transnational Spaces iv.
>   89   Son, if you can do something for your own village, if you can
>   afford to do, look that you have everything, all these things, we
>   heard about you.

I have never heard it used exactly in the way the OP quotes, but in Norfolk it was once idiomatic to say: *You look and/out...*, usually by way of an injunction to do something very important. It has perhaps declined markedly in recent years but my grandmother (1888 - 1964) used it consistently, as did my parents generation.

*He should look and take care of his sick wife, not spend all his time in the pub*, is just the sort of thing I could still hear my grandmother say about a neighbour of hers, though she has been dead for 50 years.

*You look and do as you're told*. *You look out and finish the job you started*.

The expression has the sense of enjoining you to look to a good outcome.

Comment: So you think that 'You look take care...' is a sequence that people use and understand?

Comment: @Mitch They certainly did do. Otherwise why would Shakespeare have said *...look it be done*? The form I remember is *You look and take care (what you say/how you drive etc)*. Someone has down-voted my answer. Presumably they take issue with what the OED says.

Comment: I don't see how 'look take care' maps to 'look it be done'. How is the first one syntactically like yours? They don't match functionally for me. The OED says a lot of things but it doesn't necessarily say what you want it to say.

Comment: @Mitch As I understand it, admittedly in dialect, it would be *look and take care of (your children)*, or *look out and take care of...*

Comment: 'look _and_ ...', 'look _how_ ...', 'look _that_...' are very different from 'look _take_...'. 'You look take care of her' doesn't match any of those examples in the OED.

Comment: @Mitch I did make that point in my answer, that I had not heard it used exactly as the OP had quoted. But I still think that what is being reported here falls within this OED sense 5.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include where you got this phrase, otherwise it does not make any sense. However, the sentence may have just been cut off and be "Yes, you look like you can take care of her."